# How to make WebWorkes work with typescript and webpack 5 with ts-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-worker, ts-loader

I see that in the link https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/ it is said we dont need any more worker-loader. The example is with the javascript. But how can i make it work with typescript and ts-loader with webpack 5.

ts-loader complaints in this line new Worker(new URL('./worker', import.meta.url)); syaing additional loaders are needed. I cant seem to get it woking.